# Ajax ASP.net MVC Status Response

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return a status code to my web page.
But I'm getting back a 200 and not the 201 that my controller is getting back back, which means my alert is not showing.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Request/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { model: JSON.stringify(model) },
                cache: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                statusCode: {
                    201: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    501: function(data) {
                        alert('Opps an error occurred.');
                    }
                },
                error: function(event) {
                    alert('Error' + event);
                }
            });
```

//Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Request(string model)
    {
    //Do Stuff
      return Json((int)response.StatusCode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); <-- response.StatusCode = 201
    }
```

Comment: `return Json((int)response.StatusCode...` is going to return the status code as the response body, not set the HTTP status response to the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to send status code from controller like this. i am sending HttpStatusCode.OK, it means 200

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

return Json((int)Response.StatusCode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

in ajax call

```
 statusCode: {
            200: function (data) { 
                  alert('200');
            }, 
           501: function (data) { 
                  alert('Opps an error occurred.'); 
           }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

JsonResult has no property or way for setting for HttpStatus directly.  You have to set the status code separately --

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/Request/",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { model: JSON.stringify(model) },
                        cache: false,
                        crossDomain: true,
                        async: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        sucess: function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
    ,
                        error: function(event) {
                            alert('Error' + event);
                        }
                    });
```

the status is data which is returned from json